# how to calculate and plot frequency of csv time series data from FFT

Tags: python, csv, time-series, fft, frequency-analysis

Hi i have the following data set. the data is large and here i am presenting the 1st 30 data. it is a time series of water level data with 15minute interval.

|  | datetime | time (min) | time(Sec) | WL (mm) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/2/2021 | 0:00:00 | 0 | 7109.380 |
| 1 | 1/2/2021 | 0:15:00 | 900 | 7108.028 |
| 2 | 1/2/2021 | 0:30:00 | 1800 | 7107.959 |
| 3 | 1/2/2021 | 0:45:00 | 2700 | 7109.185 |
| 4 | 1/2/2021 | 1:00:00 | 3600 | 7109.045 |
| 5 | 1/2/2021 | 1:15:00 | 4500 | 7110.831 |
| 6 | 1/2/2021 | 1:30:00 | 5400 | 7110.585 |
| 7 | 1/2/2021 | 1:45:00 | 6300 | 7110.997 |
| 8 | 1/2/2021 | 2:00:00 | 7200 | 7109.854 |
| 9 | 1/2/2021 | 2:15:00 | 8100 | 7109.671 |
| 10 | 1/2/2021 | 2:30:00 | 9000 | 7110.530 |
| 11 | 1/2/2021 | 2:45:00 | 9900 | 7110.583 |
| 12 | 1/2/2021 | 3:00:00 | 10800 | 7111.532 |
| 13 | 1/2/2021 | 3:15:00 | 11700 | 7110.585 |
| 14 | 1/2/2021 | 3:30:00 | 12600 | 7111.124 |
| 15 | 1/2/2021 | 3:45:00 | 13500 | 7111.877 |
| 16 | 1/2/2021 | 4:00:00 | 14400 | 7110.813 |
| 17 | 1/2/2021 | 4:15:00 | 15300 | 7112.031 |
| 18 | 1/2/2021 | 4:30:00 | 16200 | 7113.617 |
| 19 | 1/2/2021 | 4:45:00 | 17100 | 7111.739 |
| 20 | 1/2/2021 | 5:00:00 | 18000 | 7112.435 |
| 21 | 1/2/2021 | 5:15:00 | 18900 | 7110.201 |
| 22 | 1/2/2021 | 5:30:00 | 19800 | 7111.451 |
| 23 | 1/2/2021 | 5:45:00 | 20700 | 7111.533 |
| 24 | 1/2/2021 | 6:00:00 | 21600 | 7112.126 |
| 25 | 1/2/2021 | 6:15:00 | 22500 | 7110.860 |
| 26 | 1/2/2021 | 6:30:00 | 23400 | 7112.207 |
| 27 | 1/2/2021 | 6:45:00 | 24300 | 7110.383 |
| 28 | 1/2/2021 | 7:00:00 | 25200 | 7110.979 |
| 29 | 1/2/2021 | 7:15:00 | 26100 | 7109.918 |

i want to make the frequency distribution with frequency unit in cycles per day, i have done it through another software as follows:

[image]

how can i make the frequency plot from the  csv in python?

Comment: Hey! Could you label the axis of the graph corresponding to columns of the csv?

Comment: Hi, 5th column is the water level data. in every 15 min, the data is collected.. other three columns are the time in different formate.. so if i do the FFT.. the y axis will show the amplitude of water level and the x axis is the frequency which is cycles per day.. the water level is showing a signal with 2 cycles per day. that's why we can see a spike in 2cpd signal/.. Thanks

Comment: cycles per day means one full wavelength in 24 hours. so 2 cpd means 2 full wavelengths in 24 hours or one full wavelength in 12 hours. In more general term, the period (T) is 24 (1 day) hours for 1 cpd and 12 hours for 2 cpd.

Comment: How do you calculate the Cycles per day frequency? Do you use `np.fft.fft()`? Do you differentiate the input (the water levels measurements) prior to feeding it to the FFT function?

Comment: I have analysed the data with special software that uses the time steps and WL data to convert the time domain into the frequency domain. Thats why i am asking, how can i produce this plot using python..